# Bug in sorting when reviewing questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, sorting

If I want to sort a user's questions by newest, and then click on a question, and then go back to the user's page, SO resorts by votes instead of newest.  It seems like it doesn't remember my sorting here, even though it does everywhere else.  This is a bit of pain, and it'd be nice if it was more consistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always open the question in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Side effect of ajax in place (no postback) sorts.

Comment: There are some solutions (e.g. appending the current sort order to the URL) though. I don't think it's worth the time it takes to implement.

Comment: disagree . .this is a pain . . when going back and forth

Comment: jeff - i would expect you would be able to whip up a solution for this  in a few hours . .

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000498.html

Comment: agree that not all bugs are worth fixing but this one was raised by me . . so it should be fixed . .